# SolrCloud with separate Indexing and Search to speed up search

Tags: solrcloud, lucene-nrt

I have looked at a  lot of forum entries for this.

My use case is to **pull tons of data from a SQL Server to Solr in a denormalized schema and be able to search it fast**.

Our current UI updates the data on SQL server on a regular basis for our  operation but the search is awfully slow.We want to be able to pull all the data initially from the DB into Solr in a background batch and then be able to do delta-imports at regular imports in a batch (as frequently as possible) to keep the data as near real time as possible.I have not done any tests and am trying to come up with an Architecture based on other people's experiences to start with.

I have heard that indexing slows down querying/searching and I want to avoid that for our solution. I have been given a 10-30 min lag allowed for being able to track packages in the use case-which means being able to index the delta within the 30 mins.

The payloads are heavy though with joins across multiple tables but that is only for retrieving it and dumping it into a denormalized schema on the Solr side.The idea is to really speed up the Search and retrieval of data from the denormalized Solr schema.

My bigger worry is the data gets updated on a regular basis all around the world and it needs to be synced up thru delta-imports via some scripts at maybe 3-5 min intervals.I don't want this delta indexing process to affect the search operation at all.

10 mln rows  -->denormalized --> index size -> 30 mln rows

1000 updates/min

5000 queries/min

With the **SolrCloud approach, can I use the Master/slave approach with the Leader(as master where indexing happens) and 
replicas(on which search happens) -how exactly?**  Solr REST API will be accessed by our front-end code. 
I have also looked at the Collection Aliasing approach as another option but then the UI wil have to somehow be made to point at a new set of collections at regular intervals.

I am struggling shoe-horning Solr to handle NRT data as indexing does take time to pull data from the RDBMS into the Solr index.
Adding softCommits seems to come with its own set of gotchas to be aware of.

Any help is appreciated,

Vijay

Comment: Can I use a prefix for docId like idx!docid1 to route Indexing to a certain shard with SolrCloud ? Then Can I use q=...&_route_ != idx! to  do retrieval from the non indexing shards ? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud

Answer (score 1):

Having built a similar system to index data (~1 billions entries) in Oracle using SolrCloud version 4.3, I think you should consider the following designs challenges :

**1. Distribution of index data** : documents are distributed automatically over shards using composite router, based on the hash computed on the unique key of the document. Each shard have one leader and many replicas. You have to think seriously about the number of shards because once the cluster is created, this number is fixed. Since around version 4.4, Solr allows shards splitting BUT your cluster will not be balanced if every shard is not splitted by the same factor. At the time we have tested this feature, the implementation was still unstable. Once you have the number of shards and the potential size of each shard, you can now do the sizing of solr instances using the [estimator mentionned by buddy86](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/dev-tools/size-estimator-lucene-solr.xls).

**2. Indexing data** : access Solr REST API directly with the front end is not a good start in my opinion. You should use [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj), the solr java client, and use CloudSolrServer to index your data. This implementation matches every requirements you have expressed : updates are send directly to the leader of the shard and search queries are load balanced (round robin) between replicas. Once a document is indexed on the leader, it will be dispatched automatically to replicas using HTTP. To avoid gotchas with commit, requests use only commitWithins option (~1 minute). To scale up search capacity, you just have to add more replicas.

ETL tools provided with Solr are not used in our system because we need to index updates to the back end RDMBS on-the-fly (your use case seems to be the same), and ultimately but not so often, we need to reindex the whole database at the same time for recovery purpose. ETL tools are too simple for thoses tasks but they could match your use case.

Comment: Thx,Minh.Currently, I cannot use DIH to pull 7.8 mln recs from the DB.I pulled the data using a custom Java program into csv files of 100MB each and move it into a working directory.Then, I run full-import from the UI(could do same with a curl scipt) to pull the csv files into the Solr index.My custom java program uses a property file to store last TS and then can do the delta-import from the tables using some cron like scheduler every 10-15 mins.I have NRT setup for every 1 min and hard commit for 5 mins.I don't use CloudSolrServer as I use schema.xml and let Solr do its thing.

Comment: Any thoughts on this approach.I plan to use a separate alias for write-alias and read-alias if we need it later.How many shards and replication factor did you end up using ? Looks like you can add replicas later easily but not shards.How do you handle indexing updates ? Old master-slave replication won't work with NRT.

Comment: In our use case, we have 12 shards with 1 leader and 1 replica on each shard, distributed on two remote sites. Updates are detected by a DB trigger that writes update events in an table (just an unique id). Indexing processes crawl this table to retrieve the id and index the document.

Comment: Your approach moves a lot of data at once, hence you will be limited by the system I/O and that could hurts also the DB + Solr loads. I would recommend to stream your updates on the fly into Solr. CloudSolrServer is not the same as schema.xml. The later one defines how you want to search. CSS is part of SolrJ API that makes choice of nodes to work with.

Comment: Hi Minh, Can you contact me at bvijaykr at gmail. I have a few more questions.TIA,Vijay

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your requirements, first you need to have a very efficient SolrCloud structure. It should consist of good machines in term of CPU and RAM. Estimate your requirement by [solr size estimator](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/dev-tools/size-estimator-lucene-solr.xls).

I would suggest you to use some **ETL** (Extract Transform Load) tool for Solr indexing. It'll extract data from your RDBMS and index it to Solr. As it'll be a separate instance for Solr indexing, it'll reduce your application load.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.How will the indexing instance communicate with the SolrCloud Search instance then ?

Comment: SolrCloud can be communicated by Solr API calls or HTTP calls.